# Can I include lisp code in a text file to be executed when Emacs loads the file?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a way to add lisp code, preferably in a comment, to be executed by Emacs when it loads that file?

Specifically, I want to turn auto-fill mode off for specific LaTeX files. I know something like this can be done with a mode hook, but I don't want to do it for all LaTeX files.

The way AUCTeX for Emacs stores file-specific settings in a comment at the end of edited files leads me to suspect that something like that can be done with a general snippet of lisp, such as `(auto-fill-mode 0)` in a comment at the start or end of a LaTeX file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `add-file-local-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `eval` <kbd>RET</kbd> `(auto-fill-mode -1)` <kbd>RET</kbd>

This will add a comment at the end of the file, using the appropriate comment syntax. `eval` can contain any lisp form, but will ask to confirm for some.